# mysql: How to get SUM to ignore NULL matches

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble with this query on my database:

```
SELECT si.*, s.id, r.student_id, r.student_initial,
    SUM(( IFNULL(rl.logout_time, r.login_time) - r.login_time)/3600) AS hours,
    COUNT(r.student_id)AS attendance
FROM Staff_Log.SI_List si
    LEFT JOIN SI_Program.Sessions s ON s.si_id=si.id
    JOIN SI_Program.Sessions_Plans p ON s.plan_id=p.id
    JOIN SI_Program.Student_Roster r ON s.id=r.session_id
    JOIN SI_Program.Student_Roster_Logout rl ON r.id=rl.id
WHERE si.active=1
GROUP BY si.id, r.student_id
ORDER BY si.SI_Name, s.id, r.student_id ASC
```

My issue is that students on the Student_Roster that are open (have NULL as their matching logout time in Student_Roster_Logout) are causing the SUM to return undesirable values.  My goal is for SUM to ignore values where rl.logout_time is NULL.

I thought `IFNULL()` would work for me but I clearly don't understand how that function is working.

Comment: what is the type of ```rl.logout_time``` ?

Comment: It seems like your code should work. When `logout_time` is `NULL`, you add `0` to the sum because `r.login_time - r.login_time` is 0. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, and show what you're expecting the result to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the value of some column is NULL or not you can use:

```
some_column IS NULL
```

if you want to check whether its empty or not:

```
some_column = ''
```